# Regras e Exceções no htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess, url, url-amigável

Estou tendo um dificuldade em configurar algumas regras de rotas no meu `.htaccess`, originalmente tenho o seguinte (aceito sugestões de melhorias):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Tudo é carregado na minha index, carregando junto todas as funções do sistema, incluindo o header e o footer padrão, porém preciso adicionar duas páginas que não consumirão desse header e nem do footer. Pensei que fazendo como abaixo resolveria, mas não.

Outro ponto, esse acho que esqueci como fazer é diferenciar pastas de arquivos.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^login/?$ /login.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^start/?$ /start.php [NC,L]
```

Na minha index, tenho:

```
$modulo = Url::getURL(0);

if($modulo == null or $modulo == 'index.php'):
    $modulo = "dashboard";
endif;

if(file_exists($modulo.".php")):
    require $modulo.".php";
else:
    require "404.php";
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é criar as mesmas condições para cada regra

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^login/?$ /login.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^start/?$ /start.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Lembre-se de apagar o cache

Espero que ajude

Comment: vou testar no projeto aqui. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: A segunda opção funcionou perfeitamente, já primeira causou um loop e o deu erro 500.

Comment: Atualizei o post deixando somente o que funciona

Answer (score -4):

Exemplo:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_Host} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```